# Show three.js sprite and PlaneGeometry image completely whatever its size

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like the image to show completely whatever its size

```js
var src1 = "https://i.imgur.com/C9lWPeL.jpg",
  src2 = "https://i.imgur.com/a9zyCRt.jpg";

const src = src1;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load(
  src,
  function(texture) {
    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
      map: texture,
      color: 0xffffff
    });
    var imageWidth = spriteMaterial.map.image.width;
    var imageHeight = spriteMaterial.map.image.height;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, imageWidth / imageHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 500;
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
    sprite.scale.set(1 * imageWidth, 1 * imageHeight, 1.0);
    sprite.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(sprite);

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(700, 700 * imageHeight / imageWidth, 0);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
      color: 0xffffff
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    plane.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    //scene.add( plane );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(700, 700 * imageHeight / imageWidth);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  },
);
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<div id=container></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean _whatever its size_? Do you know why it is not displaying? If you just want to display it as a rectangle, use an `OrthographicCamera` or something. If your problem is that the image is larger than your camera, dont fix your camera size at 500... Please be a bit more specific as to what you think the problem is.

Comment: @somethinghere you guessed right I used `OrthographicCamera` and the problem was solved for `Sprite` but I can't do the same for `PlaneBufferGeometry`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Just displaying this in the orthographic camera? Creating a mesh that is the size of your picture?

Comment: @somethinghere Yes. for the `sprite` the problem is solved thanks to you but for `PlaneBufferGeometry` it's not

Comment: @somethinghere I solved the problem with `PlaneBufferGeometry` using `PerspectiveCamera` like this `var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, imageWidth/imageHeight, 0.001, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = (700*imageHeight/imageWidth)/2 / Math.atan(Math.PI/7.1);` but I don't think that this is the right way

Comment: That _would_ be the correct way if your `Math.atan()` takes the half of the `camera.fov` I think...

Comment: @somethinghere that is what I don't understand the `camera.fov` is equal to `45deg` witch mean `Math.PI/4` and the half would be `Math.PI/8`  not `Math.PI/7.1`

Comment: You would need to multiply tthe result by the aspect ratio I think. Maybe this old answer about spawning at the edge of the screen helps, as it gives you a point right outside your screen that you could use, its basically on the edge: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38925055/2991619

Comment: @somethinghere sorry I screwed up it should be `Math.tan` not `Math.atan` then everything will work right. Would you like to post the answer?

Comment: I dont think it was my answer, you found your solution so maybe answer your own question (you can). Well done!

Comment: Maybe [this is useful](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-backgrounds.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `sprite` using `OrthographicCamera` would be the best approach.

As for the `PlaneBufferGeometry` calculating the right distance that should be between the camera and the near plane like so

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, imageWidth / imageHeight, 0.001, 1000);
camera.position.z = halfHeight / Math.tan(Math.PI / 8);
```

will resolute the problem.

PS: if `plane.position.z != 0` you should add it to the camera position `camera.position.z += plane.position.z`

```js
var src1 = "https://i.imgur.com/C9lWPeL.jpg",
  src2 = "https://i.imgur.com/a9zyCRt.jpg";

const src = src1;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load(
  src,
  function(texture) {
    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
      map: texture,
      color: 0xffffff
    });
    var imageWidth = spriteMaterial.map.image.width;
    var imageHeight = spriteMaterial.map.image.height;
    var width = 700,
      height = width * imageHeight / imageWidth,
      halfHeight = height / 2;


    /*var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( imageWidth / - 2, imageWidth / 2, imageHeight / 2, imageHeight / - 2, 0, 1000 );
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
    sprite.scale.set(1 * imageWidth, 1 * imageHeight, 1.0);
    sprite.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add( sprite );*/

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, imageWidth / imageHeight, 0.001, 1000);
    camera.position.z = halfHeight / Math.tan(Math.PI / 8);
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( width, height, 0);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
      color: 0xffffff
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    plane.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(plane);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  },
);
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<div id=container></div>
```